# Proving $ \sin(\cos^{-1}(x)) = \sqrt{1 - x^2} $ without considering separate cases

Tags: trigonometry

(This feels like it could be a duplicate, but I could not find a satisfactory answer)

I want to prove
$$ \sin(\cos^{-1}(x)) = \sqrt{1 - x^2} $$

for all $x \in [-1, 1]$.

To me, the most obvious way to approach this is to set $x = \cos(\alpha), y = \sin(\alpha)$ and use $x^2 + y^2 = 1$. It's obviously enough to prove it for $0 \leq \alpha\leq 2\pi$.

I first assume $0 \leq \alpha \leq \pi$ so that $\sin(\alpha) \geq 0$ and $\alpha = \cos^{-1}(x)$. I then use $\cos(\alpha)^2 + \sin(\alpha)^2 = 1$ so that $\sin(\alpha) = \sqrt{1 - \cos(\alpha)^2}$ and substitute $\alpha = \cos^{-1}(x)$ so that we get the desired result (assuming $0 \leq \alpha \leq \pi$).

Analogously, if we assume $\pi \leq \alpha \leq 2\pi$, we get $\sin(\alpha) \leq 0$ and $\alpha = -\cos^{-1}(x)$. We use $\cos(\alpha)^2 + \sin(\alpha)^2 = 1$ to get $\sin(\alpha) = -\sqrt{1 - \cos(\alpha)^2}$ and substitute $\alpha = -\cos^{-1}(x)$. We get $\sin(-\cos^{-1}(x)) = -\sqrt{1 - \cos(\cos^{-1}(x))}$. Using $\sin(-y) = -\sin(y)$ this simplifies to the desired result.

I feel like it should be possible to avoid splitting into the two cases, and take a more unified approach. However, I am lacking insight in how it could be done.

Comment: Could you please keep the notation consistent between the symbols $x,\alpha$ and $\pi$ throughout the post? Thanks

Comment: Indeed I made two typo's where I switched x/α/π. Fixed now.

Comment: I don't really understand your logic, because "now assuming $\pi\le \alpha\le 2\pi$, which gives the same" **does not** give the same: for $\pi<\alpha<2\pi$ you have $\sin(\alpha)=-\sqrt{1-(\cos(\alpha))^2}$. That's the important fact: $\arccos(x)$ is **by definition** the angle $\alpha\in [0,\pi]$ such that $\cos (\alpha)=x$.

Comment: Should it be $\alpha$ here $\sin(\cos^{-1}(x)) = \sqrt{1 - x^2}$ instead of $x?$

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio You have $\sin(\alpha) = -\sqrt{1 - \cos(\alpha)^2}$ but also $\cos(\alpha) = -\cos^{-1}(x)$. The same steps can be followed. Of course it's not *exactly* the same, then I would need to split the cases in the first place. I will explain this more clearly in the question.

Comment: Your notation is still inconsistent.

Comment: @jjagmath you replied while I was editing. I have read the question a couple of times and think it should be OK now, but I might still be overlooking something.

Comment: @user376343 No. It should be $\cos(\alpha)$ but $\cos^{-1}(x)$. E.g. $\alpha$ is an angle, $x \in [-1, 1]$.

Comment: @Ruben when I was writing my comment, it was inconsistent.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio only after reading the accepted answer I understand the point you were trying to make. I thought your point was that I dubbed something "the same" while it was merely analogous.

Comment: @Ruben I was making two points. One was that you said that result of a calculation was the same in two cases, when it is not. The other was that you were neglecting the property that makes the whole thing work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let, $\arccos x=\theta$

$\therefore x=\cos \theta,$ Where $\theta\in\left[0,\pi\right]$ and $x\in[-1,1]$

$\therefore \sin \theta = \sqrt{1-\cos^{2} \theta}=\sqrt{1-x^2}$

We does not take $\sin \theta=-\sqrt{1-x^2}$ because $\theta\in[0,\pi]$ i.e. sine function is positive in first and second quadrant.

Hence, $\arccos x=\theta=\arcsin\sqrt{1-x^2}$

$\therefore \sin(\arccos x)=\sin(\arcsin(\sqrt{1-x^2}))=\sqrt{1-x^2}$

---

NOTE:

$\arccos x= \cos^{-1} x$ (Inverse cosine function)

$\arcsin x= \sin^{-1} x$ (Inverse sine function)

Comment: Right, I think the question is bogus since I don't need to consider the second case; $\alpha$ is always between $\pi$ and $2\pi$. My presentation of setting $x = \cos(\alpha)$ hides this, it would have been more obvious if I put $\alpha = \cos^{-1}(x)$. Thank you!

Comment: Finally you got it. By defination your $\alpha \in [0,\pi]$. Because $\cos^{-1} x $ is always in between $[0,\pi]$.

Answer (score 0):

You can prove this with a geometric argument.

Visualize a right triangle, with adjacent side of x and hypoteneuse of 1. The inverse of cosine of x, then, is the angle between the adjacent and the hypoteneuse. And because we're talking about the same triangle, that therefore makes the sine of that angle the opposite over the hypoteneuse, which by the Pythagorean theorem is $\sqrt{1 - x^2}$.

Comment: I can see it's correct when I pick the angle $\alpha$ between the adjacent and the hypotheneuse to be between 0 and $\pi$, but I still need to think about the case when $\alpha$ is between $\pi$ and $2\pi$ to see that it works.

Comment: @Ruben It works for $\alpha$ between $\pi$ and $2\pi$ because that's symmetric with $\alpha$ being from $0$ to $-\pi$.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{aligned} \because \frac{d}{d x}\left(\sin \left(\cos ^{-1} x\right)-\sqrt{1-x^2}\right) & =\cos \left(\cos ^{-1} x\right) \frac{-1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}+\sqrt{1-x^2} \\
& =-\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}+\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \\
& =0\\\therefore \sin \left(\cos ^{-1} x\right)-\sqrt{1-x^2}&=C
\end{aligned}
$$
Putting $x=0$ yields $C=0$ and hence $$
\sin \left(\cos ^{-1} x\right)=\sqrt{1-x^2}
$$